# Graphs and adjacency list practice

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Hey guys so I am currently work on a problem involving graphs and adjacency lists but it is not working. This is for self-study only and it is not for school or homework.
I am given this table of values:

```
| Start name | End name | Example path found by a search    |
|------------|----------|-----------------------------------|
| carrie     | carrie   | carrie (it's the same node)       |
| carrie     | humza    | carrie -> humza                   |
| carrie     | yervand  | carrie -> jun -> silla -> yervand |
| ophelia    | ursula   | ophelia -> travis -> **FAIL**     |
| travis     | carrie   | travis -> ophelia -> **FAIL**     |
| ursula     | ophelia  | ursula -> travis -> ophelia       |
| victor     | humza    | victor -> **FAIL**                |
```

But my code is just not working it is saying that I am not getting this:

1. from carrie to carrie
2. from carrie to humza
   And I am doing it with breath-first as recommended by them and Idk what the issue is

   ```
     if (!adjacencyList[startName]) return null;
     const queue = [startName];
     let visited = new Set();
     let currentVertex;
     if (adjacencyList[startName] === adjacencyList[endName]) return adjacencyList[startName]

     while(queue.length) {
       currentVertex = queue.shift();
       if (!visited.has(currentVertex)) {
         visited.add(currentVertex);
         adjacencyList[currentVertex].forEach(neighbor => queue.push(neighbor))
       }
     }
     if (visited.has(endName)) {
       return visited;
     }
     else {
       return null
     }
   }
   ```

Idk what the issue is and how to fix it. I thought that by returning the set I would return the path but apparently not.

Comment: Oh btw here is the adjecency list provided:
'carrie':  ['humza', 'jun'],
   'farrah':  ['humza'],
   'humza':   ['carrie', 'farrah', 'jun', 'silla'],
   'jun':     ['carrie', 'silla'],
   'ophelia': ['travis'],
   'silla':   ['humza', 'yervand'],
   'travis':  ['ophelia'],
   'ursula':  ['travis'],
   'victor':  [],
   'yervand': ['silla']

Comment: And here what I am supposed to get
{'startName': 'carrie',
     'endName': 'carrie',
     'visited': ['carrie']},
    {'startName': 'carrie',
     'endName': 'humza',
     'visited': ['carrie', 'humza']},
    {'startName': 'carrie',
     'endName': 'yervand',
     'visited': ['carrie', 'jun', 'farrah', 'yervand', 'humza', 'silla']},